# Jquery Auto Slider with buttons

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, jquery-animate, css-animations

Can anyone recommend any good product auto slider with buttons. I am new to jquery so any good easy jquery slider would be fine. I am looking to build this kind of [slider](http://oi62.tinypic.com/339k9hj.jpg) 
.And when click on the image then it should open the clicked image with description [like this](http://oi57.tinypic.com/15mcj83.jpg) . Any help of how can i make this slider would be appreciated thanks in the advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

popup: [colorbox](http://www.jacklmoore.com/colorbox/)

slider: [elastislide-responsive-carousel](http://tympanus.net/codrops/2011/09/12/elastislide-responsive-carousel/)

http://jsfiddle.net/ckraoftt/1/

**HTML:**

```
<div class="column">
    <ul id="carousel" class="elastislide-list">
        <li><a href="img4.jpg"><img src="img44" alt="image04" /></a></li>
        <li><a href="img3.jpg"><img src="img33" alt="image03" /></a></li>
        <li><a href="img2.jpg"><img src="img22" alt="image02" /></a></li>
        <li><a href="img1.jpg"><img src="img11" alt="image01" /></a></li> 
    </ul>
</div>
```

**JQ:**

```
$( '#carousel' ).elastislide( {
    orientation : 'vertical'
} );

$('#carousel a').colorbox({photo :true});
```

---

**EDIT2:**

http://jsfiddle.net/ckraoftt/7/

for all a tag add 2 attr:

```
data-txt="image 4 4000$" //text after image

data-button-url="http://test.com/shop/4"  //url for button Shop
```

**JQ**

```
$( '#carousel' ).elastislide( {
    orientation : 'vertical'
} );

$('#carousel a').colorbox({
    html:function(){

        var src=$(this).attr('href');
        var txt=$(this).attr('data-txt');
        var url=$(this).attr('data-button-url');

        var img='<img src="'+src+'">';
        var text= '<div class="pp_txt">'+txt+'</div>';
        var btn='<a class="pp_btn" href="'+url+'">SHOP</a>';

        var html='<div class="popup">'+img+text+btn+'</div>';
        return html;
    }
```

Comment: can i also add some text with button like this(http://oi57.tinypic.com/15mcj83.jpg) when an image is clicked